# Gaps in between recyclerview items when view inside item is shown/hidden

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recycler view with linear layout manager, based on some logic I am hiding/showing a view inside recycler view item.

**Issue** Problem occurs when I scroll, I can see some gaps in between recycler view item, which are random when scroll. If I hide the view always , then there is no issue, but I need to show and hide based on some logic and when implemented the gaps are coming as well.

**Assumption** One thing I am sure of is that the issue is there because of hiding/showing a view.
[image]

Comment: An image and some code would help here. But to take a blind stab in the dark - try setVisibility(GONE) instead of hide or INVISIBLE. It sounds like there is a good chance your constraining views incorrectly for this use case

Comment: @NickCardoso I have added the image, actually I am use visibility as gone.

Comment: @NickCardoso You were right, it was showing becasue of not constraining views properly, once constrained, it was working perfect. Thanks